# an ajax http request terminated abnormally readystate undefined when a file uploading in drupal 7

Tags: ajax, http, drupal, cck

When uploading a >20 mb file through cck in drupal 7, there is the following error:

```
ajax http request terminated abnormally,ready state undefined
```

What is causing this error? How to solve it?